# reachability.m and .h + Global UIVIew for error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I added the reachability.m and .h files. When theres no internet connection, i want to display a UIView which is semi transparent and and comes up at the bottem like a Toolbar saying *No internet Connection Available*

I've got the code etc.. but i need a way to display the UIView i created and to push it to the front of everything when im using NAvigationControllers to control my application.

Could someone assist? Just need a way to push the UIView to the front but keep the nav controller on its current view so it can still go back and forth, the UIView is just a little transparant at the bottem like a pop up warning of no internet connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the view to float above all other views but not respond to user input.  You could make a new UIWindow to put the UIView in.  Set the `windowLevel` of the window high enough to order it above other windows.  Or you could add the view to the superview or window of the navigation controller.

```
[theNavController.view.window addSubview:theMessageView];
```

You could add it directly to the navigation controller view, but I think that is discouraged.

Comment: If i use that, it adds it ontop of the current view? or to the "hierarchy" so its a new view being pushed and the back button then responds to going back to the original view, if that makes sense? i dont want that, i want the first part you described about, how would i call that new UIWindow so its high enough to be ontop?

Comment: The windowLevel of the main window is 1, so anything higher than that should work.  A new window may be opaque by default.

Comment: Thanks, I can try using that, but once i displayed it, how do i undisplay it, or hide it if internet is available?

Thanks

Comment: Also, I made a new UIWindow, with a new UIView and a label that says No Internet, and typed in

[navigationController.view.window addSubview:NoInternet];

But it doesnt bring it up